# Facebook graph API rate limit and batch requests

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I've seen the 600 calls / 600 seconds rate limit mentioned by some (e.g. on [quora](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit)).

What I want to know is whether I am allowed to do 600 [batch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) requests in 600 secs (a batch request consists of up to 50 requests).

Comment: "We currently limit the number of batch requests to 50." - [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). 50 what? Requests per minute, day, user!?

Comment: I was wanting to know the same thing. 50 concurrent requests, requests per minute, per day, per diaper change???

Comment: Hmm.. I wanted to make fun of FB, but reading their documentation clarifies things: "We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a batch to 50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same manner."

Comment: So batching really serves the sole purpose of reducing HTTP load/latency, and since bigger HTTP requests are bulkier and more prone to timeout errors, I'd rather just stick with non-batched requests, or just batch together only requests for small datasets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should handle the rate limiting programmatically by checking for the following error message.  You should then put in a time-wait loop before your next call if you encounter the error.  One of my high traffic applications accounts watches for this error and will slow down.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/bestpractices/

> **Rate limited (API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS)** If your application is making too many calls, the API server might rate limit you automatically,
>   returning an "API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS" error. Generally, this should not
>   happen. If it does, it is because your application has been determined
>   to be making too many API calls. Iterate on your code so you're making
>   as few calls as possible in order to maintain the user experience
>   needed. You should also avoid complicated FQL queries. To understand
>   if your application is being throttled, go to Insights and click
>   "Throttling".

**edit**

As reported by Igy in the comment thread, each request in that batch counts as 1.  For your example of 600 being the max limit, that means you can fire off 15 batch requests containing 50 calls each.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the best practices. However my question is if batched requests and single requests both count as 1 request against the limit.

Comment: If Facebook's docs doesn't say which is being done, then you should error on the side of caution in order to not let your developer account become flagged/revoked and monitor the Errors being returned from the API.  It's best practice to monitor those errors and do what they say.

Comment: Link is not working anymore? I need to implement rate limiting, what kind of response do i get back?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to the original question? I'm well aware that you should handle the too many calls error code, but I still want to know if batch requests counts as multiple requests in terms of the API rate limit.

Comment: Someone has filed a bug report about this earlier in the year, though there is no official answer from FB. I suggest we all hit `Reproduce` so that it is elevated in priority: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/122223527918914/

Comment: You will never find an official answer to your question on the exact number.  First Facebook uses dynamic algorithms to determine the number acceptable per user/application.  The nummber changes all the time based upon the criteria used by those dynamic algorithms.

Comment: A Batch request of 50 counts as 50 API calls - the main advantage is setting dependencies and lowering the number of round-trip calls to the API - it doesn't affect the call or resource limits though

Comment: Now, here is the kicker.  What access token do these rates apply to? I have a batch process which imports posts for ~800 accounts, and even though I set an explicit access token for each request in a batch request, I am still getting rate limited if I don't restrict it to a total of 1 request per second overall (regardless of token).

Comment: To see "Insights", go to [Facebook Insights](https://www.facebook.com/insights/), click on the App for which you would like to get insights to, then click "App Insights" -> "Developer".

Comment: @thefreeman: what if you don't use batching and use the tokens separately?

Comment: @ErikAllik I have since moved away from batching and have stopped running into the rate limiting issue.

Answer (score 8):

According to FB docs, each element in a batch counts as a separate call.

> We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a
>   batch to 50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for
>   the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For
>   example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call
>   within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same
>   manner.

Quoted from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

I don't have empirical evidence however.

David

Answer (score 6):

From my experience, they count individual requests regardless the way they were made (in batch or not).

For example, if I'm trying to do 1 batch/sec containing 10 requests each, I soon get 'TOO MANY CALLS'.

If I'm doing 1 batch/10 sec, each batch containg 10 requests, I never see TOO MANY CALLS.

I personally do not see any reason to prefer batches over regular API calls.

Answer (score 5):

I have quite a big and painful experience now with the Facebook API and I can state that :

- If a batch request contains 50 requests, then it counts as 50 requests on Facebook
- 1 request != 1 call. Facebook has its own definition of what a call is. If your request is big, return a lot of data or consume a lot of cpu then it will count as several calls.

The most frequent graph API call I am doing contains a lot of nested fields and I have noticed that I reached the  "600 calls / 600 seconds" after doing it only 200 times. So basically this call count for 3 in my case...

You have a lot of other rate limits but none of of them are properly documented...

Answer (score 2):

Batch calls definitely are counted per item in the batch. One batch call with 50 items is the equivalent of 50 api calls using the graph.