# How should I insert a bunch of data in Meteor Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

It's taking a long time to save 500+ Facebook friends in MongoDB and I think I'm doing it so wrong. I'll paste how I'm doing the insertion:

models.js:

```
Friends = new Meteor.Collection('friends');
Friend = {
set : function(owner, friend) {
    var user_id = get_user_by_uid(friend['uid']);
    return Friends.update({uid: friend['uid'], owner: owner}, {$set:{
        name : friend['name'],
        pic_square : 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+friend['uid']+'/picture?width=150&height=150',
        pic_cover : friend['pic_cover'],
        uid : friend['uid'],
        likes_count : friend['likes_count'],
        friend_count : friend['friend_count'],
        wall_count : friend['wall_count'],
        age : get_age(friend['birthday_date']),
        mutual_friend_count : friend['mutual_friend_count'],
        owner : owner,
        user_id : user_id ? user_id['_id'] : undefined
    }}, {upsert: true});
}
}
```

server.js:

```
// First get facebook list of friends   
friends = friends['data']['data'];

_.each(friends, function(friend){
    Friend.set(user_id, friend);
});
```

The loads go high with 2+ users and it takes ages to insert on the database. What should I change here ?

Comment: Why are you using Friends.update instead of Friends.insert?

Comment: Try inserting the data and see if the speed improves. Also note that upsert isn't supported in minimongo yet (the client-side implementation of mongodb in Meteor)

Answer (score 4):

The performance is bad for two reasons I think.

First, you are experiencing `minimongo` performance, not `mongodb` performance, on the client. `minimongo` can't index, so `upsert` is expensive—it is `O(n^2)` expensive on database size. Simply add a `if (Meteor.isSimulation) return;` statement into your model just before the database updating.

Take a look at some sample code to see how to organize your code a bit, because `Friend.set(user_id, friend)` should be occurring in a method call, conventionally, defined in your `model.js`. Then, it should escape if it is detected as a client simulating the call, as opposed to the server executing it.

Second, you are using `uid` and `owner` like a key without making them a key. On your server startup code, add `Friends._ensureIndex({uid:1, owner:1})`.

If none of this works, then your queries to Facebook might be rate-limited in some way.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805436/1757994 for some discussion about the error message you'd receive if you are being rate limited.

They almost certainly do not want you copying the graph the way you are doing. You might want to consider not copying the graph at all and only getting the data on a use-basis, because it very rapidly becomes stale anyway.

Comment: Friend.set is occuring inside a method call. I'll try the other points. BRB

Comment: Did: `set : function(owner, friend) {var user_id = get_user_by_uid(friend['uid']); if (Meteor.isSimulation) return; [...]` and put the _ensureIndex in Meteor.startup of server. Is it required to erase the collection/db or something ?

Comment: No, I don't think you have to erase anything. If you don't see a performance improvement, and you are indeed querying Facebook for each line, then you are being rate limited. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805436/1757994

Comment: I don't see any huge improvements. I'll need to change my algorithm and don't do upserts. Thanks for the help.